# NodeJS - Two same I2C address BME280 sensors connected through TCA9548A multiplexer (clashing results)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sensors, i2c

Good evening everyone!

For some reason there are a lot information on TCA9548A in Python, but not much on NodeJS.

I was trying to use this library from Github [TCA9548A](https://github.com/coreymjacobs/tca9548a) with this library [BME280](https://github.com/fivdi/bme280)

Both BME280 sensors have address 0x76.

TCA9548A - 0x70.

The final code I was running was this:

```
const tca9548a_1 = new TCA9548A({addr: 0x70, bus: 1});

//as an example, if using two bme280 temp sensors (sensor1 and sensor2)
//that have the same address need to enable the specific 
//multiplexer port each time you want to read from a certain device
//singlePortOn activates the port of the argument and 
//disables all other ports
//argument has to be a number 0-7
//
//use a callback to ensure that the port is enabled 
//before proceeding with other processing
//
//for example, sensor1 is attached to port 2 on the multiplexer
//
tca9548a_1.singlePortOn(2, doSomethingWithSensor());

//then read from sensor2 attached to port 6 on the multiplexer
//
tca9548a_1.singlePortOn(7, doSomethingWithSensor());


function doSomethingWithSensor () {
  //process sensor data magic
const bme280 = require('bme280');

const format = number => (Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
const delay = millis => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));

const reportContinuous = async _ => {
  const sensor = await bme280.open({
    i2cBusNumber: 1,
    i2cAddress: 0x76,
    humidityOversampling: bme280.OVERSAMPLE.X1,
    pressureOversampling: bme280.OVERSAMPLE.X16,
    temperatureOversampling: bme280.OVERSAMPLE.X2,
    filterCoefficient: bme280.FILTER.F16
  });

  for (let i = 1; i <= 250; ++i) {
    const reading = await sensor.read();
    console.log(
      `${i} ` +
      `${format(reading.temperature)}°C, ` +
      `${format(reading.pressure)} hPa, ` +
      `${format(reading.humidity)}%`
    );
    await delay(1000); // 1 second
  }

  await sensor.close();
};

reportContinuous().catch(console.log);

}
```

Output and the problem: Only one sensor is being read and is outputting information that is doubled. This code is not reading information from them both, but just from one.

I am not very strong in JavaScript, but really want to learn.
Seems like I need to create a callback - from this comment in the code:

**//use a callback to ensure that the port is enabled before proceeding with other processing**

Will greatly appreciate any help on this subject.

Comment: And why are you not using in-kernel drivers for mux and for sensors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked for me:

```
const TCA9548A = require('tca9548a');
const i2c = require('i2c-bus');

const tca9548a_1 = new TCA9548A({ addr: 0x70, bus: 1 });

function two(callback) {
    tca9548a_1.singlePortOn(2);
    console.log("Two")
    const bme280 = require('bme280');
    bme280.open().then(async sensor => {
        console.log(await sensor.read());
        await sensor.close();
    }).catch(console.log);
    callback()
}

function seven(callback) {
    return setTimeout(() => {
        tca9548a_1.singlePortOn(7);
        console.log("Seven")
        const bme280 = require('bme280');
        bme280.open().then(async sensor => {
            console.log(await sensor.read());
            await sensor.close();
        }).catch(console.log);
        callback()
    }, 1000);    
}

function run() {
    two(() => {
        seven(() => { })
    })
}

run();
```

OUTPUT:

```
Two
{
  temperature: 28.303820903622544,
  pressure: 991.7407636221005,
  humidity: 39.50036416630162
}
Seven
{
  temperature: 24.77324210727238,
  pressure: 991.0048461479205,
  humidity: 25.391542980733707
}
```